# Problems with nested async functions (async waterfall in async series)

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, asynchronous, async.js

Please some help with this, im new with nodejs and this is a common issue and  and im tried the examples in anothers posts here. I have problem when in the last function.

Im trying:

1. Check if a data.json exists and create it with a some data with async.waterfall

```js
function IfDataDontExistsCreate(callback)
{
    async.waterfall([ //If data dont exists
        function IfExistDataFile(callback) {
            fs.exists(path, function(exists){
                if(!exists)
                {
                    try {
                        const firstDataFile = {"readedPosts":{"id": []}};
                        const json = JSON.stringify(firstDataFile, null, 2);
                        callback(null, json);
                    } catch (error) {
                        callback(error);
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        )},
        function CreateDataFile(json ,callback) {
            fs.writeFile(path, json, function (err) {
                if(err) callback(err);
            })
        }
    ], function (err, callback) {
        if(err) throw err;
    });

    callback(null, callback);
}
```

2. Read data.json, get data, add some info and save data.json with async.waterfall

```js
function AppendtoDataFile(info, callback)
{
    async.waterfall([
        function ReadGetData(callback) {
            fs.readFile(path, (err, data) => {
                if(err) throw err;
                let datajson = JSON.parse(data.toString());
                datajson.readedPosts.id.push(info.toString()); //Add info
                callback(err, datajson)
            })
        },
        function WriteDataFile(data, callback) {
            const writeData = fs.writeFile(path, JSON.stringify(data, null, 2), function (err) {
                if(err) throw err;
                callback(err);
            })
        }
    ], function(err, callback)
    {
        if(err) throw err;
    });

    callback(null, callback);
}
```

3. Join the functions with async.series

```js
function AddPostID(postID, callback)
{
    async.series({
        one: function (callback) {
            IfDataDontExistsCreate(function () {
                callback(null, "DataFile Created");
            });
        },
        two: function (callback) {
            AppendtoDataFile(postID, function () {
                callback(null, "PostID added to Datafile");
            });
        }
    }),
    function (err, results) {
        if(error) throw err;
        console.log(results);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is EXACTLY why promises were invented.  They create a much more sane mechanism for chaining, nesting or branching asynchronous operations.  Even better when used with `await`.

Comment: Reading your code, you're missing multiple callbacks, or calling the same one multiple times... As @jfriend00 said, you should be using promises.

Comment: uhmm but the modules used work with callbacks functions and these stuff..

Comment: Yes, of course they do, but since we got promises now, why don't use them. Have a look at my answer, I ported your code to promises. Let me know if you have any doubts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure about the exact problem you are facing but I do see an issue in your code. The `callback` in both functions `IfDataDontExistsCreate` and `AppendtoDataFile` is being called before async waterfall completes execution.

Calling `callback(err, null)` from final callback of async.waterfall and removing last line i.e. `callback(null, callback)` from both the functions should fix issue for you.

Answer (score 3):

Since your specific problems has been answered by @Raeesaa,
I'm providing an alternative using promises and `async/await`, making the code more readable & clean

First of all, you can avoid `fs.exists` using `fs.writeFile` with `wx` flag:

> 'wx' - Like 'w' but fails if the path exists.

---

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const { promisify } = require('util');

const writeFile = promisify(fs.writeFile);
const readFile = promisify(fs.readFile);

const path = '/tmp/foo.json';

async function IfDataDontExistsCreate() {
    const firstDataFile = {
        readedPosts: {
            id: []
        }
    };

    const json = JSON.stringify(firstDataFile, null, 2);

    try {

        await writeFile(path, json, { flag: 'wx' });
    } catch(e) {
        // If EEXIST means the file is already created, do nothing
        if(e.code !== 'EEXIST')
            throw e;
    }
}

async function AppendtoDataFile(info) {

    const data = await readFile(path, 'utf8');

    let datajson = JSON.parse(data);
    datajson.readedPosts.id.push(info.toString()); // Add info

    return writeFile(path, JSON.stringify(datajson, null, 2));
}

async function AddPostID(postID) {

    // Wait until the file is created
    await IfDataDontExistsCreate();
    console.log('DataFile Created');

    // We append after the file has been created
    await AppendtoDataFile(postID);
    console.log('PostID added to Datafile');

    return true;
}

AddPostID(5)
  .then(res => console.log('Done!'))
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: Why do `const { promisify } = require('util');` instead of `const promisify = require('util').promisify;`?  I know destructuring is the latest gizmo to play with, but why use it with just one property?

Comment: To be honest, I coded it on a project I had open, where eslint nags about destructuring, so I just went with the flow. Is still shorter though.